# I'm creating a socket proxy with vert.x and it's not working well

Tags: java, sockets, proxy, vert.x

I am creating a socket proxy with vert.x version 3.9.
Mysql is working fine, but mongodb is not, where should I look?

The code looks like this

```
public class VertxProxy extends AbstractVerticle {

    // Convenience method so you can run it in your IDE
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
        vertx.deployVerticle(new VertxProxy(), new Handler<AsyncResult<String>>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(AsyncResult<String> asyncResult) {
                if (asyncResult.succeeded()) {
                    System.out.println("====>  SUC");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("====>  FAIL");
                    asyncResult.cause().printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {
        NetServer netServer = vertx.createNetServer();
        NetClient netClient = vertx.createNetClient();

        netServer.connectHandler(socket -> {
            netClient.connect(27017, "127.0.0.1", result -> {
                NetSocket clientSocket = socket;
                NetSocket serverSocket = result.result();

                // user -> localserver:port
                clientSocket.handler(buffer -> {
                    System.out.println("send clint to server");
                    byte[] _byteBuff = buffer.getByteBuf().array();

                    serverSocket.write(buffer);
                });

                serverSocket.handler(buffer -> {
                    System.out.println("send server to clinet ");
                    byte[] _byteBuff = buffer.getByteBuf().array();

                    clientSocket.write(buffer);
                });

            });
        }).listen(33404, listenResult -> {
            if (listenResult.succeeded()) {
                System.out.println("->  succ");
            } else {
                System.out.println("-> fail");

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Mysql works fine, but mongodb does not work with the proxy.  Where should I look?